# Растягивание формы в Qt

Tags: qt

Привет всем! Интересно как сделать так чтобы при изменении размера приложения формы растягивались, а не оставались в прежнем размере.

Answer (score 6):

Используйте, так называемые, лэйауты `(QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout...)`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, они же и "компоновщики"

Comment: @gil9red точно, а также менеджеры расположения. Лэйаут - "птичий жаргон" )